# Quickbooks how to create customer then create customer job

Tags: xml, api, quickbooks

So we have code which creates a customer, and then a customer Job. The customer job fails for inexplicable reasons.

Here is the initial request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?><?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq newMessageSetID="c80f653c176ed1e5975e" onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerAddRq>
            <CustomerAdd>
                <Name>xxxx. (20615)</Name>
                <CompanyName>xxxx</CompanyName>
                <Salutation/>
                <FirstName/>
                <MiddleName/>
                <LastName/>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>xxxx</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>xxx</Addr2>
                    <Addr3/>
                    <Addr4/>
                    <City>xxx</City>
                    <State>xx</State>
                    <PostalCode>xxxxx</PostalCode>
                    <Country>USA</Country>
                    <Note/>
                </BillAddress>
                <Phone>000000</Phone>
                <Fax>000000</Fax>
                <Email/>
                <Contact/>
                <TermsRef>
                    <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
                </TermsRef>
            </CustomerAdd>
        </CustomerAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

And the relevant portion of the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRs newMessageSetID="3368552138367687637">
        <CustomerAddRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
            <CustomerRet>
                <ListID>80000118-1272906278</ListID>
                <TimeCreated>2010-05-03T13:04:38-05:00</TimeCreated>
                <TimeModified>2010-05-03T13:04:38-05:00</TimeModified>
                <EditSequence>1272906278</EditSequence>
                <TermsRef>
                    <ListID>80000006-1244039697</ListID>
                    <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
                </TermsRef>
                <Balance>0.00</Balance>
                <TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
                <JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
            </CustomerRet>
        </CustomerAddRs>
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

We go back to Quickbooks with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?><?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq newMessageSetID="0da30b5086cd3938febe" onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerAddRq>
            <CustomerAdd>
                <Name>xxxxxxx</Name>
                <ParentRef>
                    <ListID>80000118-1272906278</ListID>
                </ParentRef>
                <CompanyName>xxxxxxx</CompanyName>
                <Salutation/>
                <FirstName/>
                <MiddleName/>
                <LastName/>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>xxxxx</Addr1>
                    <Addr2>xxxxx</Addr2>
                    <Addr3/>
                    <Addr4/>
                    <City>xxxx</City>
                    <State>xxx</State>
                    <PostalCode>xxxx</PostalCode>
                    <Country>USA</Country>
                    <Note/>
                </BillAddress>
                <Phone>00000000</Phone>
                <Fax>0000000</Fax>
                <Email/>
                <Contact/>
                <TermsRef>
                    <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
                </TermsRef>
            </CustomerAdd>
        </CustomerAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

And Quickbooks then responds to that second request with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRs newMessageSetID="0da30b5086cd3938febe">
        <CustomerAddRs statusCode="3240" statusSeverity="Error"
                       statusMessage="Object &quot;80000118-1272906278&quot; specified in the request cannot be found. "/>
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

The first response is at 2013-01-21 10:34:22.353 and the second at 2013-01-21 10:35:21.080 (server time).

Why is it failing? Note that it often works. In this request sequence alone it created two others without issues using the same commands.

Sometimes for good measure it responds with this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRs newMessageSetID="215932fd6e1fffdd574c">
        <CustomerAddRs statusCode="3120" statusSeverity="Error"
                       statusMessage="Object &quot;11A0001-1289401726&quot; specified in the request cannot be found.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list."/>
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

How do you ensure that a customer just created is in the list to reference in the next command?

Comment: Your qbXML looks correct, this looks like bad behavior on the part of QuickBooks. Have you tried adding a delay between the customer and the job add messages?

Comment: Can you do a customerquery for that listId? Does anything show up?

Comment: @William. Yes, afterwards you can query on it and it does exist.

Comment: @PaulKeister, it does delay (as you can see by about a minute) but the thing is it is active then (there are a bunch of customers and customer jobs going on, either query or create) in that scenario. A delay is certainly an option (and perhaps even the solution, unfortunately). Users won't like that, though. Essentially a delay is telling quickbooks no more requests on the web services integration, and then waiting for the next time it asks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the timestamps; that is a long time to wait for consistency! Sorry I don't have a solution, but I am very interested in your results. I curious: have you confirmed the scenario in which the customer is visible for a customer query message by not visible for a customer add? I'm wondering if perhaps a retry algorithm might use a query to verify that the customer record had been committed.

Comment: Can you link to the API documentation you're using? I've noticed they have a few.

Comment: @SamerBechara, http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

Comment: If you add a customer ID without a list number, is it added to a default list, or is it added to a new list?

Comment: @SamerBechara, you mean the ParentRef? The difference between a customer with a ParentRef and one without, is that the one without is a regular customer. The one with is a Customer Job.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying a <FullName> and using that instead of <ListID>? There's a curious section in Chapter 15 of the SDK Guide called "A Note about ListIDs" that indicates something may be changing the ListID when you attempt to add a job.

Comment: That is a good find, thanks. But no, that isn't the issue, as the user hasn't had a chance to modify the customer. What that is saying is that you can convert a customer into a customer job, creating a new entity as its parent. So you might think that the customer changed its ID, but that isn't what happened. Here the user would not have had a chance to do that, and either way the ID would still exist, although I don't know off hand if you can create a nested customer job (two levels down).

Comment: However, referencing the full name is an option. Unfortunately it would be very complicated because this is the only context where I actually have it. For updates we store the quickbooks ID.

Comment: I expected that you might not have much <FullName> support in your application. It is rarely used. That note in the manual looked like some developer found a "feature" and wanted to cover it with some documentation. That's what made me suspicious that your issue had been found before. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the customer as **active** within your `<CustomerAddRq>` when you create the customer?

```
    <CustomerAddRq>
        <CustomerAdd>
            <Name>xxxx. (20615)</Name>
            <IsActive>1</IsActive>
            <!-- rest of the details... -->
        </CustomerAdd>
    </CustomerAddRq>
```

Comment: We don't set the customer as active. I guess on a new request we could (on a Mod we never would). What indicates to you that this could make a difference? That should be the default.